# Cohomology classes $H^{1,1}(M, \mathbb{C})$ on Kaehler manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, de-rham-cohomology

I am confused about this and I would appreciate your help.

Suppose you have a Kaehler manifold $(M, \omega).$ Let $\omega_1, \omega_2$ be two $(1,1)$ forms belonging to different cohomology classes in $H^{1,1}(M, \mathbb{C})$. Is it possible that they both belong to the same class in $H^2(M, \mathbb{C})$?

How are $H^2(M, \mathbb{C})$ and $H^{1,1}(M, \mathbb{C})$ related to each other?

Thank you.

Comment: In general $H^n = \bigoplus H^{p,n-p}$ where the sum is over all $p$ from $0$ to $n$ inclusive.So in particular in your case, $H^{1,1}$ is a summand of $H^2$.

Comment: A reference to get started is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_theory#Hodge_theory_for_complex_projective_varieties In spite of the section heading, the decomposition I wrote is valid for all compact Kaehler manifolds.

Comment: @LazzaroCampeotti  Got it, thank you. Can you help with my first question too: is it possible that they both belong to the same class in $H^2 (M,\mathbb{C})$? I don't think so, but checking if I understand correctly.

Comment: No, that is not possible. $H^{1,1}$ is a subset of $H^2$. So, if you like, to say that a form $\omega$ is a $(1,1)$ form means that its cohomology class $[w]$, which by definition is an element of $H^2$, happens to lie in the subset $H^{1,1}$. So to say that two $(1,1)$ forms have different cohomology classes in $H^{1,1}$ means that their cohomology classes are different elements of $H^2$, both of which happen to be in $H^{1,1}$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it is clear to me now.  Thank you.